# Anticommutation relation for the Weyl spinors in Minkowski space+time

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, second-quantization, chirality, anticommutator

For $D$-dimensional Minkowski space+time, I suppose that the Dirac spinor has the following anticommutation relation:
$$
\{ \psi(x_1), \psi(x_2)\}=\{ \psi^\dagger(x_1), \psi^\dagger(x_2)\}=0
$$
$$
\{ \psi(x_1),  \psi^\dagger(x_2)\}=\delta^{D}(x_1-x_2)
$$
in the spacetime.
Or for the equal time,
$$
\{ \psi(\vec{x_1}),  \psi^\dagger(\vec{x_2})\}=\delta^{D-1}(\vec x_1-\vec x_2).
$$

When $D$ is even, we can have Weyl spinors,
$$
\psi(x )=\psi_L(x )+\psi_R(x ).
$$

My question is that

> What is the anticommutation relation for the Weyl spinors? Is that
> $$
> \{ \psi_a(x_1), \psi_b(x_2)\}=\{ \psi^\dagger_a(x_1), \psi^\dagger_b(x_2)\}=0
> $$
> $$
> \{ \psi(x_1),  \psi^\dagger(x_2)\}=\delta^{D}(x_1-x_2)
> $$
> in the spacetime.
> Or for the equal time,
> $$
> \{ \psi_a(\vec{x_1}),  \psi^\dagger_b(\vec{x_2})\}=\delta_{ab}\delta^{D-1}(\vec x_1-\vec x_2).
> $$
> where $a$ and $b$ are in $L$ or $R$ while $\delta_{LR}=0$ and $\delta_{LL}=\delta_{RR}=1$?

Comment: Hint: how are the Weyl spinors obtained from the Dirac spinors?

Comment: there is an issue of projection of $\psi$ into the Weyl, and projection of $\psi^\dagger$ into the Weyl - also the hardness issue. This is why I asked about it... Could you clarify?